# Why is there no rule to make target needed by another target in my makefile

Tags: make

When I run the makefile at the bottom, I receive the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'xhtml/%.html', needed by 'manifold/01_doehmer_syntax_pre.zip'.  Stop.
```

I do not understand this error, because there is a rule with target `xhtml/%.html`. Why does this rule not count?

I run this in a folder that contains the file `01_doehmer_aspekte.docx`.

```
BINDIR:=~/TEIC-XSLT/bin
PROFDIR:=/mnt/c/Users/niels-oliver.walkows/OneDrive/Dokumente/Luxemburg/Melusinapress/Transformationen/xslt/TEIC/profiles
MANUSCRIPTFILE:=$(shell ls *.docx)
MANUSCRIPTNAME:=$(shell basename ${MANUSCRIPTFILE} .docx)

.PHONY : all clean

all: manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip

tei/%.xml: %.docx
    mkdir -p tei
    ${BINDIR}/docxtotei --profiledir=${PROFDIR} --profile=melusina $< $@

xhtml/%.html: tei/%.xml
    mkdir -p xhtml
    ${BINDIR}/teitohtml --profiledir=${PROFDIR} --profile=melusina $< $@
    cp -r tei/media xhtml/

manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip: xhtml/%.html
    mkdir -p manifold
    touch manifold/manifest.yml
    cp -r tei/media manifold/
    cp -r xhtml/*.html manifold/
    cd manifold && zip -r ${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip manifest.yml media *.html
    rm -rf manifold/media manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.html

test:
    echo "${MANUSCRIPTFILE}"
    echo "${MANUSCRIPTNAME}"

clean:
    rm -rf tei xhtml manifold
```

Comment: In `manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip: xhtml/%.html`, there's no `%` in the target `manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip`, so what is the `%` in the prerequisite supposed to match?

Comment: does that mean, I can only use make wildcards when it may appear on both sides (target and dependency)?

But what would I do then, when a clearly named target depends on an undefined number of dependencies?

Comment: Yes. From https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern : "Each target is matched against the target-pattern to extract a part of the target name, called the stem. This stem is substituted into each of the prereq-patterns to make the prerequisite names (one from each prereq-pattern). [...] When the target-pattern matches a target, the ‘%’ can match any part of the target name; this part is called the stem."

Comment: You can use wildcards: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcards

Comment: `%` in not a glob, it is a pattern matching character. You used it in place of a glob (`manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip: xhtml/%.html`). It was interpreted as a literal character.

Comment: that was also helpful and I now see that my confusion  has raised from the fact that the tutorial I used called % the make version of * which, I now see, it is really not. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the goal `xhtml/%.html` you are not creating a recipe for a single file, but a recipe for **all files that match this pattern**, i.e. all files in `xhtml/` with a `.html` suffix, for instance `xhtml/foobar.html`.

For instance when we put the following goals:

```
xhtml/%.html: xml/%.xml
    xsltproc magic.xsl $< > $@

xml/foobar.xml:
    echo '<?xml version="1.0"?><a><b><c some="attr">Lorep Ipsum</c><c some="other">Dorlor si amet</c></b></a></xml>' >$@
```

we may now run `make xhtml/foobar.html` and make will determine that `xhtml/foobar.html` depends on `xml/foobar.xml` and will therefore first look to create `xml/foobar.xml` for which we have a recipe at hand.

The `%` can be read as "allow arbitrary text" and `make` remembers this arbitrary text for further use. So when we run `make xhtml/foobar.html`, `make` recognises `foobar` as "arbitrary text", remembers `foobar` and evaluates the goal as if we had written `xhtml/foobar.html: xml/foobar.xml`.

When you put `xhtml/%.html` as a dependency, you are refering to the arbitrary part of the goal. Similarly, `make xhtml/hello.html` will fail, because `make` will not be able to find a rule to make `xml/hello.xml`.

In your Makefile, when `make` reaches the recipe `manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip: xhtml/%.html` it cannot find an arbitrary part in the goal, because it is a static file name. As a result it has nothing to replace the `%` with and I think that is just considered an error.

I do not know what you want to replace the `%` (and so doesn't make), but I think you can improve your code with this:

```
manifold/$(MANUSCRIPTNAME).zip: manifold/%.zip: xhtml/%.html
```

Notice that there are now two `:` in this line. The new middle component tells `make` how to read a sensible value for `%` from your filename.

Alternatively you can put:

```
# as your first recipe
default: manifold/$(MANUSCRIPTNAME).zip

# and then
manifold/%.zip: xhtml/%.html
    [...your recipe...]
```

Or even:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL: manifold/$(MANUSCRIPTNAME).zip
manifold/%.zip: xhtml/%.html
    [...your recipe...]
```

But I think the last is GNU Make only.

P.S.: I think its very strange that `make` seems to (be able to) dereference `${}`. Usually I would expect we use `$()`-constructs.

Comment: Both `$(foo)` and `${foo}` are valid ways to reference variables in a Makefile, nothing strange about that: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference . Oh and this is not a GNU Make specific feature, all make's (AFAICT) behave the same way. For variable names which consist of a single character, the syntax `$x` is also valid.

Comment: I find the solution involving a default rule (`default: manifold/$(MANUSCRIPTNAME).zip` as the first rule in your Makefile) much better than the one setting up a static pattern for that specific name only (the one you listed first), so I'd suggest listing that one first in your answer and the other one (`$(MANUSCRIPTNAME).zip: %.zip: %.html`, with paths) as an alternative approach to also be considered. By convention, the default rule is usually called `all`, so that a command such as `make all` will execute the same (building all default targets), so I'd use that name instead.

Comment: `.DEFAULT_GOAL` is an esoteric back door which should probably be avoided, the manual's example of it reinforces that impression: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html . Just instruct on using a default target by placing it first in the Makefile, that's the correct way to do that. (BTW, I *think* that variable is *not* GNU make specific, but that point is somewhat moot if you end up removimg that part from the answer.)